# Spark - How to move persisted data from disk to cache?

Tags: apache-spark

I run into a pretty simple but frustrating pattern when doing adhoc data analysis:

You have `rdd1` cached in memory, then cache `rdd2` in memory, which evicts `rdd1` to disk because of memory constraints. If you were to unpersist `rdd2`, is there anyway to tell spark to move `rdd1` back to memory?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to instruct spark to bring the rdd1 back to memory.
But, next time the rdd1 is accessed, it gets loaded into memory, given that you are using MEMORY_AND_DISK persistence level (otherwise it gets recomputed).

If you are looking to reduce space and load in memory, consider using MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER, this will serialize your objects and store.